# Order Crossover (OX) - genetic algorithm

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

Can someone explain me how Order Crossover works? I will give this example and I want to understand it in a generic way to implement after.

Parent 1 = **1 2 3 | 4 5 6 7 | 8 9**

Parent 2 = **4 5 2 | 1 8 7 6 | 9 3**

and the solution are two childreen:

Children 1 = **2 1 8 | 4 5 6 7 | 9 3**

Children 2 = **3 4 5 | 1 8 7 6 | 9 2**

I understand some parts but others not.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One such solution for Ordered Crossover is detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782881/how-to-implement-ordered-crossover).

This answer provides some sample java code with documentation detailing the processes used for the Ordered Crossover.

Additionally, [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.1898&rep=rep1&type=pdf) from Moscato provides a breakdown of the OX Process.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your link to Moscato's paper has died over the years. [Here's](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.1898&rep=rep1&type=pdf) a new one.

Comment: @Muroxxas, thanks I have updated the link.

Answer (score 22):

Basically, a swath of consecutive alleles from parent 1 drops down, and remaining values are placed in the child in the order which they appear in parent 2.

[image]

Step 1: Select a random swath of consecutive alleles from parent 1. (underlined)

Step 2: Drop the swath down to Child 1 and mark out these alleles in Parent 2.

Step 3: Starting on the right side of the swath, grab alleles from parent 2 and insert them in Child 1 at the right edge of the swath. Since 8 is in that position in Parent 2, it is inserted into Child 1 first at the right edge of the swath. Notice that alleles 1, 2 and 3 are skipped because they are marked out and 4 is inserted into the 2nd spot in Child 1.

Step 4: If you desire a second child from the two parents, flip Parent 1 and Parent 2 and go back to Step 1.