# Retrieve a specific permutation without storing all possible permutations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, permutation, genetic-algorithm, nested

I am working on 2D rectangular packing. In order to minimize the length of the infinite sheet (Width is constant) by changing the order in which parts are placed. For example, we could place 11 parts in 11! ways.

I could label those parts and save all possible permutations using `perms` function and run it one by one, but I need a large amount of memory even for 11 parts. I'd like to be able to do it for around 1000 parts.

Luckily, I don't need every possible sequence. I would like to index each permutation to a number. Test a random sequence and then use GA to converge the results to find the optimal sequence.

Therefore, I need a function which gives a specific permutation value when run for any number of times unlike `randperm` function.

For example, `function(5,6)` should always return say `[1 4 3 2 5 6]` for 6 parts. I don't need the sequences in a specific order, but the function should give the same sequence for same index. and also for some other index, the sequence should not be same as this one.

So far, I have used `randperm` function to generate random sequence for around 2000 iterations and finding a best sequence out of it by comparing length, but this works only for few number of parts. Also using `randperm` may result in repeated sequence instead of unique sequence.

Here's a picture of what I have done. 
[image: Packing example]

I can't save the outputs of `randperm` because I won't have a searchable function space. I don't want to find the length of the sheet for all sequences. I only need do it for certain sequence identified by certain index determined by genetic algorithm. If I use `randperm`,  I won't have the sequence for all indexes (even though I only need some of them).

For example, take some function, 'y = f(x)', in the range [0,10] say. For each value of x, I get a y. Here y is my sheet length. x is the index of permutation. For any x, I find its sequence (the specific permutation) and then its corresponding sheet length. Based on the results of some random values of x, GA will generate me a new list of x to find a more optimal y.

I need a function that duplicates `perms`, (I guess `perms` are following the same order of permutations each time it is run because `perms(1:4)` will yield same results when run any number of times) without actually storing the values.

Is there a way to write the function? If not, then how do i solve my problem?

**Edit (how i approached the problem):**

In `Genetic Algorithm`, you need to crossover parents(permutations), But if you crossover permutations, you will get the numbers repeated. for eg:- crossing over `1 2 3 4` with `3 2 1 4` may result something like `3 2 3 4`. Therefore, to avoid repetition, i thought of indexing each parent to a number and then convert the number to binary form and then crossover the binary indices to get a new binary number then convert it back to decimal and find its specific permutation. But then later on, i discovered i could just use `ordered crossover` of the permutations itself instead of crossing over their indices.

More details on `Ordered Crossover` could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518393/order-crossover-ox-genetic-algorithm)

Comment: How many of the permutations do you expect to use? Could you just store a list of those you have already used and check against it when you get a new value from `randperm`? This would be less expensive if the number of permutations you use is small.

Comment: You can number permutations as you see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Numbering_permutations), but the problem then becomes how to get a numeric type with the range to express the values `0..1000!`.

Comment: edited to make it clear why i cant use 'randperm'

Comment: You could right a function to generate permutations in lexographical order, but only return the nth permutation. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) gives a possible algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are two functions that together will generate permutations in lexographical order and return the nth permutation

For example, I can call

```
nth_permutation(5, [1 2 3 4])
```

And the output will be  `[1 4 2 3]`

Intuitively, how long this method takes is linear in `n`. The size of the set doesn't matter. I benchmarked `nth_permutations(n, 1:1000)` averaged over 100 iterations and got the following graph

[image: Benchmark graph of n vs time]

So timewise it seems okay.

```
function [permutation] = nth_permutation(n, set)
%%NTH_PERMUTATION Generates n permutations of set in lexographical order and
%%outputs the last one
%% set is a 1 by m matrix

set = sort(set);
permutation = set; %First permutation

for ii=2:n
   permutation = next_permute(permutation);    
end

end

function [p] = next_permute(p)
%Following algorithm from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order

%Find the largest index k such that p[k] < p[k+1]
larger = p(1:end-1) < p(2:end);
k = max(find(larger));

%If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
if isempty(k)
    display('Last permutation reached');
    return
end

%Find the largest index l greater than k such that p[k] < p[l].
larger = [false(1, k) p(k+1:end) > p(k)];
l = max(find(larger));

%Swap the value of p[k] with that of p[l].
p([k, l]) = p([l, k]);

%Reverse the sequence from p[k + 1] up to and including the final element p[n].
p(k+1:end) = p(end:-1:k+1);

end
```

Comment: Actually i moved on with another way to solve the problem. but this could be a great solution for someone having similar problem. I didn't test this, but this is what i was looking for. thanks and +1

Comment: Glad you found another solution! Best of luck.

Comment: @SanthanSalai you should post what you ended up using as an answer.

Comment: Actually what i meant was i avoided this problem itself instead of finding different way to solve this specific problem. In GA, you need to crossover parents, i thought of indexing each parent(permutation) to a number and then convert the number to binary form and then crossover the binary indices to get a new binary number -> convert to decimal -> find their specific permutation. But then, i discovered i could just use ordered crossover of the permutations itself instead of crossing over their indices. @neuronet

Comment: Details for ordered crossover can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518393/order-crossover-ox-genetic-algorithm). Did i help you? @neuronet